# jQuery + bootstrap slider, only the first slide animates properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, slideshow

I'm trying to create a simple automatic sliding banner with jQuery. I have bootstrap included as well and I can't seem to get an entering animation on anything other than my first slide. I'm extremely new to JS and jQuery in general. any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require_once '/core/init.php';
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?v=<?=time();?>">  <!--v=<//?=time();?> forces css reload for. testing only-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="slider()">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Site</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="slider" class="slider">
      <?php headDispFile() ?>
    </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
 <!--php-->
<?php
  function headDispFile(){
    $imageDisplay = "";
    $images = scandir("img/header/");//scan directory
    $ignore = array(".","..");//ignore extra directory back and forward controls
    $i = '1';//set counting var $i to 1 as a string
    foreach ($images as $file) {//for each element in the images array
      if(!in_array($file, $ignore)){ //make sure ignore strings are not the name of the file
        $imageDisplay .= '<img id="'.$i.'" src="img/header/'.$file.'" class="hDisp"/>';//img html code to echo $i concatinated as string
        $i++;//incrament count
      }
    }
    echo $imageDisplay; //echo html
  }

 ?>
 <!--javascript-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function slider(){//declare function
     $(".slider #1").show("fade",500);//html with class="slider" and an id="1" fade in over 500ms
     $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);//after 5500 ms delay hide the slide offscreen slide left 500ms
     var sc = $(".slider img").size();//get number of imgs in slideshow via class attribute tag
     var count = '2';//move to next slide

     setInterval(function(){//over a set interval
       $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500);//slide in slide 2 from right
       $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);//slide out slide 2 from left
       if (count == sc) {//if current slide is the last slide
         count = '1';//loop to slide 1
       }else{
         count++;//incriment slide
       }
     },6500);//declare interval for setInterval loop
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: $(".slider #"+count).effect('slide', {direction: 'right', duration: 500}); – b4rtekb Feb 15 at 18:38. I wonder if I could do $(".slider #"+count).effect('slide', {direction: 'right', mode: 'hide', duration: 500}); havent tested any of this yet.

Comment: ok so in response to my previous comment I found the issue. .show() and .hide() are both using the .effect() from Jquery UI. The real issue was the setInterval delay.  Upping the value of the setInterval delay to 7000 worked for the example above and values of 500ms greater than the total delays solved the issues no matter the function's internal total. Possibly a result of image loading? Not sure though.